# Why is sqlpsx not included in SQL Server itself?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I know there is a project called [sqlpsx](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/) and it provides some powershell based replication management capability.

- Does anyone know why the SQL Server team doesn't include this feature in
  SQL Server itself?
- Does SQL Server 2008 R2 have this capability?
- What about the newest version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of sqlpsx is that it can be installed on any version of SQL Server (2000+) and works as an extension side-by-side to SQL Server. If it were to be rolled into SQL Server, then you lose some of that flexibility of being independent.  The project itself started as an initiative outside the formal SQL Server product, mostly by Chad Miller himself.

As a standalone, it can have the usual disclaimer `use at your own risk`, can be updated frequently, does not need to be included in regression tests of the SQL Server product suite (which is already a massive task to test) etc

It is still a standalone for SQL Server 2008 R2 (you need to install it separately).

There doesn't seem to be any plans on the horizon to include it in Denali.